# How to iterate a function on my data frame and get values stored in the same data frame with the original values

Tags: python, pandas, loops, iterated-function

The below is the function for finding probability(for being in a class) for one id(with multiple features and their one values) at a time. How would I iterate this function over an excel sheet having multiple rows and multiple features. I would like to add new columns next to existing columns showing the probability value which we will get by the below function. I have converted the data frame to dictionary, where column names are keys. SO, I have multiple values in each keys.

```
def predict_many(values, features):
    values = np.array(values).reshape(-1, 1)
    features = np.array(features)
    results = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=features, columns=["X_value"])
    results["proba"] = results.apply(lambda row: predict_one(row.X_value, row.name), axis=1).values
    return results
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on  how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question may also be useful.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You are mixing a lot of stuff in this function and question. You can use either the dataframe or dictionary, try one, give it a go, show what you did and what happened we will be better able to help that way.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [`df.iterrows()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html)?

Comment: yes, I have tried this but no success-                                                                                                   def predict_many(values, features):
    for key, value in df.items():

Comment: @Tanya Then please add what error you are coming up with and possibly the stacktrace?

Comment: I am not getting any error as I do not know what exactly to do to achieve this, I need a way on how to do this as I am new to python.

Comment: or else I want something like this---predict_many([[21,22],[22,23]],["CR","QR"]) where I can pass a list on one feature, so in one go I can pass multiple features with their multiple values.

Answer (score 0):

To apply a function similar to yours to each key value pair in a dictionary we would iterate over the dictionary passing the key value pairs, since the function returns a df we would then concat the dfs as they are returned

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
for key, value in d.items():
     temp_df = function_to_apply(key, value)
     df2 = pd.concat([df2, temp_df])
```

The dictionary you will be using may need to be transformed in order to get the desired results.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it. But may be I am not able to express my query. Let me rephrase it, how would I apply this function on my dataframe. I will later see how to store in the columns.

Comment: This cannot be applied to a dataframe, as what you are left with after this is a dataframe. I recommend breaking everything up as much as possible so you are doing lots of small simple things... will make it easier. I get the impression you may have gotten a bit lost in it all.

Comment: I understand it can not be applied to the dataframe, I have converted the dataframe to dictionary, how can this function be applied on all values of all keys?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have this function                                                                                                                        def predict_one(values, feature):
    value = np.array(values).reshape(-1, 1)
    model = modelDict[feature]
    res = list(model.predict_proba(value)[:, 1])
    return res if len(res)-1 else res[0]     for one column and the above predict_many for multiple columns, but I am getting errors in both. While using predict_one error is- Shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (1, 11). What change should I make in this case

Comment: sorry for the error in above comment, shape of passed values is (1, 1), indices imply (1, 11). is the error while using predict_many and error- 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed is while using predict_one.

Comment: would you mind rewriting your original question with all this info, hard to follow without formatting. and include as much data as possible. a quick print of the dict, the dfs at each stage all that.